# Contains all elements and duplicates are taken into account

Tags: algorithm, kotlin

The idea is to have a function which checks if all elements in a list are contained in another list. But not just the containedness has to be true, but also **the times** of containedness.

One could say the function has to be an extended version of [containsAll](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/contains-all.html) , which checks only the containedness.

Here's my implementation of such a function:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val toCheck = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 1, 3)
    val expected = listOf(1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4)

    val result = containsAllSameCount(toCheck, expected)
    println("Result => $result")

    val expected2 = listOf(1, 1, 3, 3, 4) // One 1 is missing!
    val result2 = containsAllSameCount(toCheck, expected2)
    println("Result 2 => $result2")
    /*
        Result => true
        Result 2 => false
     */
}

fun containsAllSameCount(toCheck: List<Int>, expected: List<Int>): Boolean {
    for (current in expected) {
        var currentInExpected = expected.filter { it == current }
        var currentInToCheck = toCheck.filter { it == current }

        if (currentInExpected.size != currentInToCheck.size) {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

It's clear to me, that the filter-methods are used multiple times, when the same element is contained multiple times. Therefore I suppose that my implementation isn't the most efficient way to solve the task.

**What do you think about my implementation?**

**What's a better way to solve the way?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way would be to change data structure. Instead of using a `List<Int>` you can use a `Map<Int, Int>`. If you want to have a `List<Int>` in the beginning, that's ok, you just need to convert it to a `Map<Int, Int>` and compare the maps.

Using the nice Kotlin methods in the stdlib, we can make the code into this:

```
fun <T> containsAllSameCount(toCheck: List<T>, expected: List<T>): Boolean {
    val toCheckCountMap = toCheck.groupBy { it }.mapValues { it.value.size }
    val expectedCountMap = expected.groupBy { it }.mapValues { it.value.size }
    return expectedCountMap.all { toCheckCountMap[it.key] == it.value }
}
```

I have also added generics here because the same logic applies whether it's a `List<Int>`, `List<String>` and so on.

Some other notes:

- Use JUnit for proper tests.
- The `main` method in Kotlin does not need to be declared with the `args`, simply `fun main() {` will do.
- Use `val` instead of `var` whenever possible.
- Instead of `.filter` and then checking the size, use `.count`